# CSS - space between the bullet and the list without padding the list

Tags: css, list, margin, padding, offset

I'm spending hours hunting a solution on internet. It seems there is no answer to my question.

I use simple liste like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

my `list-style-type` is `lower-alpha` . Until there it's quite basic.

Problem: The `list-style-type` is not aligned to my grid.

[image]

**Question: How can I offset the `list-style-type` in order to create a space of 20px to the left without touching the `<li>`'s padding?** All the solutions I've found on the internet says to add padding to the `<li>` and create a compensation if needed to stick the grid.

I want to achieve this :

[image]

**to**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a pseudo element?

This process can offer complete control over the bullets position and shape.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '•';
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

### Bullets with incremental characters

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: Count;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(Count, lower-alpha) ".";
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

### Bullets with incremental integers

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: Count 1;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(Count) ")";
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ohh I like that... It's possible to to that with alpha instead of bullet sign? because most of time i have to enumerate a line of thought and order has importance

Comment: you're a chief ! Exactly what I need. be blessed =)

Comment: I would, but I don't believe I have editorial privileges which is why I posted the comment. I'll be glad to delete it though since you corrected it. Thanks!